# linux tcsh scripting question

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I am writing a linux `tcsh` script to check the syntax of a command argument to insure its correct before the command executes.
Out of the 9 fields I have saved as variables in the script, I am able to get 7 of them checked. I only have 2 remaining and they are both confounding me with the same issues.
The first one is a check of "tco14" or "tc14a" these are 2 examples of the same field I need to have the script check.
The preceding 2 examples will always break down like this:
"tc" will always begin this argument followed by the next 2 positions which should be numbers between 1-9 then the final position which can be either a number or a letter.

In bash I had it working with these lines:

```
# Check the seventh field
check_field "$var7" 'TC([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z])$' "Field 7 is not valid:" 7
```

That script used arrays in getting the cheeck accomplished, HOWEVER as I found out in tcsh it doesnt play nice with ALOT of bash scripting. So Ive tried the following in tcsh:

```
# Check if field7 matches the specified format
set valid_field7 = `expr "$field7" : '^tc[0-9]\{1,3\}[a-zA-Z0-9]$'`

if ($valid_field7 == 0) then
    echo "${RED}Error: Invalid syntax for field7. Must start with 'tc' followed by 2 digits and end with a digit or a letter.${NC}"
    exit 1
endif
```

This almost works but it also passes the check with tc12 which it shouldnt. Again this field of the argument needs 3 character the first 2 are numbers and the last one is a number or a letter. Reference following lines for possibly a better understanding:

- First Position = t
- Second Position = c
- Third Position = number between 0-9
- Fourth Position = number between 0-9
- Fifth Position = a letter or a number between 0-9

Comment: If you want exactly 2 digits before the final letter-or-digit, wouldn't that be `\{2\}` rather than `\{1,3\}`? or skip the quantifier and make it explicit `[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: You'll get more reliable code if you can avoid writing the script in (t)csh, and instead write it in one of the bourne shell variants such as `bash`. There's nothing wrong with having a shell script written in a different language to the shell you prefer to use interactively

Comment: Regarding "I am writing a linux tcsh script" - don't do that, see any of the articles returned by [https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not) but https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt is a good start. That's not just a preference thing, [t]csh just isn't designed for scripting - it's like saying you're going to dig a hole with a tooth brush.

Comment: Thanks but I am religated to using tcsh as that is what the script i am adding it to is written in.. tcsh is a pain..